# SQL Server File Operations?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, file-io

Using SQL Server 2005: How can I read a file into a SPROC using T-SQL?

So, imagine I have a CSV file like so:

```
ID,OtherUselessData
1,asdf
2,asdf
3,asdf
```

etc...

I basically want to do this:

```
Select * from mytable where id in (select id from txtFile)
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [OPENROWSET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx) function to open/parse you CSV file and use it as a 'row source' (i.e. like a table)

Answer (score 2):

here are some examples: http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/reading-and-writing-files-in-sql-server-using-t-sql/

Comment: ya, I saw that already and will use it if needbe, but that's a custom sproc that he wrote and I thought there was a built-in sqlserver way to do this?

Comment: you should at least look at that procedure's code, there is no need to build your own wheel...