# Read contents from txt file using T-SQL

Tags: t-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL Server File Operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302099/sql-server-file-operations)

Is there by any chance I could use T-SQL to read the first line of a txt file?
Actually, I have a csv file and the first line is the name of all hundreds of columns. I have already coded the part where I could use the first line to generate a table with all that columns. So, really want to figure out how to do the reading part.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at the [BULK INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) statement.